# Customize the container shape

Tags: flutter, containers, scrollview, customization, clip-path

How to achieve following shape in flutter without using plugins? I want to implement the customized container using clippath. I'm trying to use lineTo() method. I did not get exactly this one.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this package, [clippy_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/clippy_flutter), using Point:

```
            Point(
              triangleHeight: 30.0,
              edge: Edge.LEFT,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.pink,
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                child: Center(child: Text('Point')),
              ),
            ),
```

and then stack them and overlap a little at the egde.